# Sails.js & Mysql select/insert.. from database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

Im new to node.js and sails.js.

I have added mysql and changed the config file etc..

What I would like to get help with is how I make a query to the database, Im used to php and I feel this not really the same.

I have searched and don't really find something that helps me..

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use [`node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) or even [`sequelize.js`](http://sequelizejs.com/)

Comment: I have already connected to the database, but i donät understand how to get data and inset data in the database with Sails.js.